# H/W: C++ Error "trying to initialize Abstract base class"

Tags: c++, inheritance, stack, polymorphism

Trying to initialize a class called StackAsLinkedList, which should be a derived class of the abstract class Stack (testing code which is available here: http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus4/).

However, I get an error trying to instantiate this code in main():

```
StackAsLinkedList stack;

error C2259: 'StackAsLinkedList' : cannot instantiate abstract class
```

I am confused about this, because I thought StackAsLinkedList is defined as a derived class of Stack:

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include "object.h"
#include "linkList.h"
#include "container.h"

class Stack : public virtual Container
{
public:

    virtual Object& Top () const = 0;
    virtual void Push (Object&) = 0;
    virtual Object& Pop () = 0;
};

class StackAsLinkedList : public Stack
{
    LinkedList<Object*> list;

    class Iter;

public:

    StackAsLinkedList () : list() {}
    ~StackAsLinkedList() { Purge(); }

    //
    // Push, Pop and Top
    //
    void Push(Object& object);
    Object& Pop();
    Object& Top() const;

    //
    // purge elements from, and accept elements onto, the list
    //
    void Purge();
    void Accept (Visitor&) const;

    friend class Iter;
};

class StackAsLinkedList::Iter : public Iterator
{
    StackAsLinkedList const& stack;
    ListElement<Object*> const* position;

public:

    Iter (StackAsLinkedList const& _stack) : stack(_stack) { Reset(); }

    //
    // determine whether iterator is pointing at null
    //
    bool IsDone() const { return position == 0; }

    //
    // overloaded dereference and increment operator
    //
    Object& operator*() const;
    void   operator++() const;

    void Reset() { position = stack.list.Head(); }
};

#endif
```

The implementation:

```
#include "stack.h"

void StackAsLinkedList::Purge()
{
    if ( IsOwner() )
    {
        ListElement<Object*> const* ptr;

        for(ptr = list.Head(); ptr != 0; ptr = ptr->Next() )
            delete ptr->Datum();

        list.Purge();
        count = 0;
    }
}

void StackAsLinkedList::Push(Object& object)
{
    list.Prepend(&object);
    ++count;
}

Object& StackAsLinkedList::Pop()
{
    if(count == 0)
        throw domain_error ("stack is empty");

    Object& result = *list.First();
    list.Extract(&result);
    --count;
    return result;
}

Object& StackAsLinkedList::Top() const
{
    if(count == 0)
        throw domain_error ("stack is empty");

    return *list.First();
}

void StackAsLinkedList::Accept(Visitor& visitor) const
{
    ListElement<Object*> const* ptr;

    for(ptr = list.Head(); ptr != 0 && !visitor.IsDone(); ptr = ptr->Next())
    visitor.Visit(*ptr->Datum());
}
```

class Container:

```
#ifndef CONTAINER_H
#define CONTAINER_H

#include "object.h"
#include "visitor.h"
#include "iterator.h"
#include "ownership.h"

class Container : public virtual Object, public virtual Ownership
{
protected:

    unsigned int count;
Container () : count(0) {}

public:

    virtual unsigned int Count () const { return count; }
    virtual bool IsEmpty () const { return Count () == 0; }
    virtual bool IsFull () const { return false; }
    //virtual HashValue Hash () const;
    virtual void Put (ostream&) const;
    virtual Iterator& NewIterator () const { return *new NullIterator (); }

    virtual void Purge () = 0;
    virtual void Accept (Visitor&) const = 0;
 };

 #endif
```

EDIT: It appears that the compiler says that the CompareTo() method in Object is not implemented in any of the derived classes. However, this functionality is implemented in the derived class of Object called "Wrapper":

```
#ifndef WRAPPER_H
#define WRAPPER_H

#include "object.h"


template <class T>
class Wrapper : public Object
{
protected:

    T datum;
    int CompareTo (Object const&) const;

public:

    Wrapper ();
    Wrapper (T const&);
    Wrapper& operator = (T const&);
    operator T const& () const;
    //HashValue Hash () const;
    void Put (ostream&) const;
};

//
// typedefs for for Wrappers representing different primitive
// data types
//
typedef Wrapper <int> Int;
typedef Wrapper <char> Char;
typedef Wrapper <double> Double;
typedef Wrapper <std::string> String;

#include "wrapper.inc"

#endif
```

But Stack doesn't inherit from Wrapper - so I am guessing this means another CompareTo method needs to be implemented for Stack? Not sure how the original author got this to work (scratches head).

Comment: What compiler are you using?  With either MSVC++ or a newer version of gcc, you can write `Object& Pop() override;` and the compiler will let you know if it doesn't match.  You also need to show any warnings that the compiler spit out alongside that error.

Comment: You need to show the definition of Container

Comment: @DeadMG: I think you need to make that an answer, it's almost certain to be the issue.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: it appears it is a problem with "Object":  'int Object::CompareTo(const Object &) const' : is abstract

Comment: @Dylan: Probably `StackAsLinkedList` inherits `Stack` inherits `Container` inherits `Object`?  Then somewhere along the way, you must define what `CompareTo` means for a `StackAsLinkedList`.

Comment: what's the definition of `Container`?

Comment: Indeed. CompareTo() is implemented in Wrapper (which inherits from Object), but it doesn't seem that Stack inherits from Wrapper... hmmm... again this is largely source code which someone else wrote - i am trying to understand it.

Comment: @Dylan: Now that you understand why it's failing, I suggest you move on to understanding good code.  Not only is this code obviously not tested, it exhibits terrible style.  Probably because it's trying to use the same design in multiple languages, and the C++ code is actually a poor translation of the Java version, not a C++ design.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I would normally take your suggestion, but the ostensible goal of this assignment is to look at old code which doesn't really work anymore and figure out what is wrong with it (and fix it). Figured out where the problem is, not sure about how to solve it without completely scrapping the current design!

Comment: @Ben Voigt, Dylan: better and more useful yet is to understand the `std::stack` template from the standard library. Fixing idiomatically Java inspired code like this is like teaching a hippo how to dance.

Comment: @Alexandre: I took a course on STL prior to this class (Data Structures), and believe me, I would totally use STL if I could (no STL allowed)

Comment: @Alexandre: I'd probably start by understanding a simple templated stack class, and only move on to all the subtleties of the STL implementation after the basic operations are well understood.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Understanding why top + pop and not just pop is the only subtlety of `std::stack` (and probably what you're talking about). But I get your point. Also @Dylan, you should really fix that `Pop` method to return `void`.

Comment: @Alexandre: really? I thought after popping an element of the stack you want to get back the object (or a pointer to the object)?

Comment: @Dylan: The point is that you cannot pop and return the element in the same function. If copying the top object (at the return statement) fails for any reason (ie. *throws an exception*), you want the stack to remain untouched. Therefore, you provide `top` for getting the top element, and `pop` for removing the top element. This is how the `std::stack` class does, and one of my pet reasons for telling people not to implement stack classes themselves.

Comment: @Alexandre: Copying a pointer is non-throwing.  This collection only holds pointers(necessary for polymorphism), no copies of elements are being made.  Understanding the rationale for a design decision, and where it doesn't apply, is more important than fixating on it and making it into an inviolable rule.

Comment: @Dylan: You're fine, what Alexandre is talking about only refers to collections which store values, not collections which store pointers.  Your collection stores pointers and returning the pointer from `Pop` is fine.

Comment: In fact, having separate operations for `top` and `pop` is a serious mistake when it comes to concurrent collections.

Comment: @BenVoigt My bad, I only contemplated the fact that `Top` is returning a reference. In this case, you *must* return a pointer from `Pop` or the reference becomes dangling. (Also, `std::stack<std::unique_ptr<T>>` would provide the desired semantics here). Also concurrent collections are another bag of worms (whom I would *never* want to implement myself).

Comment: @AlexandreC: The reference isn't dangling, the object is dynamically allocated and will continue to exist until its address is used as the operand of `delete`.  Agreed that using a pointer is far better style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've now explained you're trying to fix it, I suggest:

- First step is to get it compiling, which you can do by adding a `CompareTo(Object&) const` member to `StackAsLinkedList`.  You can use either `dynamic_cast` or the `Visitor` machinery to find out whether the object compared to is another collection.
- Next, get rid of reference parameters in any case where the object will be stored by the callee and used after the function returns.  And eradicate reference return types, where ownership is being transferred.  You can either use pointers, or change the collection to pass-by-value (but don't pass-by-value if the collection should be polymorphic).  You'd get:

  ```
  class Stack : public virtual Container
  {
  public:
      virtual Object& Top () const = 0; // short-term access to object, no ownership transfer, reference is ok here.
      virtual void Push (Object*) = 0;  // pointer kept, ownership transfer, use pointer
      virtual Object* Pop () = 0;       // ownership transfer (caller must delete), use pointer
  };
  ```
- Then, you should do something about the brokenness in the `Visitor` implementation.  Right now, `Accept` always calls `Visit(Object&)` regardless of the dynamic type.  You'd need to call a virtual `Accept` function on each individual member, in order to let the `Visitor` perform correctly on polymorphic collections.

We're well on the way to scrapping the design by this point.